# Setting desktop background results in inaccurate image colors

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, desktop-background

I'm a new Ubuntu user since last night and so far I'm liking it.

However I've run into one particular problem(among others), namely when I download a photo using chrome and set it as a background, the colors are inaccurate.

Inaccurate meaning: the desktop background has lighter colors.
Example below:

Downloaded picture:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

rgjoni